# What is "Localhost" binding in DNS forwarder in pfSense?

Tags: freebsd, dns, pfsense

Trying to debug some network problems, I found that my DNS forwarder is configured in the following way:

[image]

Although many entries stands for my WAN interfaces and LAN stands for LAN one, I don't understand, what does `Localhost` mean?

Answer (score 1):

The `localhost` entry is always "the machine you are currently logged in to". It's also referred to as `loopback`, though that's more the interface name than the host name. The IP address is 127.0.0.1.

Comment: What will happen if I remove this binding?

Comment: Anything that depends on it will break. It's generally not a good idea to do that unless you have a deep understanding of the system in question.